# Grid of equations in aligned environment, each with own references

Tags: equations, align, labels, subequations, tags

I would like to achieve something like the example shown in the picture below.

[image]

I already have a solution; however, it seems to involve creating *a lot* of minipages and subequation environments, plus the equations don't up. I'd like the equals signs to all line up, and for there to be no discrepancies in vertical alignment (e.g. equation 6a versus 6b/c) within each row, or horizontal alignment (e.g. (6a)-(6c) does not line up with (7a)-(7c) or (8a)-(8c)). I would like each equation in the grid to have its own tag and reference, so that I can cite them later, rather than have to make a generic label for each row and only be able to cite that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\global\long\def\pd{\partial}%
\global\long\def\div{\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot}%
\global\long\def\grad{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}%
\global\long\def\curl{\boldsymbol{\nabla}\wedge}%
\global\long\def\lap{\nabla^{2}}%
\global\long\def\a{{\rm a}}%
\global\long\def\at#1#2{\left.#1\right|_{#2}}%
\global\long\def\ve#1{\bf #1}%
\global\long\def\jumppm#1{\mathbf{\left[#1\right]_{-}^{+}}}%

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{(#3#1#4)--(#5#2#6)}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\hsize}
\begin{equation}
    \jumppm{\varepsilon\ve{E}\cdot\ve{n}} &= \xi, \notag
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
    \label{eq:E.n-jump}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\hsize}
\begin{equation}
    \jumppm{\ve{B}\cdot\ve{n}} &= 0, \notag
    \label{eq:B.n-jump}
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\hsize}
\begin{equation} 
    \jumppm{\ve{J}\cdot\ve{n}} &= 0, \notag
    \label{eq:J.n-jump}
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\cref{eq:E.n-jump,eq:B.n-jump,eq:J.n-jump}
\end{subequations}
\begin{subequations}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\hsize}
\begin{equation}
    \jumppm{\ve{E}\cdot\ve{t}_1} &= 0, \notag
    \label{eq:E.t1-jump}
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\hsize}
\begin{equation}
    \jumppm{\dfrac{1}{\mu}\ve{B}\cdot\ve{t}_1} &= 0, \notag
    \label{eq:B.t1-jump}
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\hsize}
\begin{equation} 
    \jumppm{\dfrac{1}{\sigma}\ve{J}\cdot\ve{t}_1} &= \jumppm{(\ve{u}\cross \ve{B})\cdot\ve{t_1}}, \notag
    \label{eq:J.t1-jump}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\cref{eq:E.t1-jump,eq:B.t1-jump,eq:J.t1-jump}
\end{subequations}
\begin{subequations}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\hsize}
\begin{equation}
    \jumppm{\ve{E}\cdot\ve{t}_2} &= 0, \notag
    \label{eq:E.t2-jump}
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\hsize}
\begin{equation}
    \jumppm{\dfrac{1}{\mu}\ve{B}\cdot\ve{t}_2} &= 0, \notag
    \label{eq:B.t2-jump}
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\hsize}
\begin{equation} 
    \jumppm{\dfrac{1}{\sigma}\ve{J}\cdot\ve{t}_2} &= \jumppm{(\ve{u}\cross \ve{B})\cdot\ve{t_2}}, \notag
    \label{eq:J.t2-jump}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\cref{eq:E.t2-jump,eq:B.t2-jump,eq:J.t2-jump}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Surely there must be a more elegant way to do it than this?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. We have no idea how you defined `\jumppm` & Co. And while this is not entirely relevant to answer the question, it makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I have added a MWE just now.